# sun.security.validator.ValidatorException

Tags: java, https

I have desktop app.
The task is to add https protocol for loading file.
There is one way

```
 static public void test(){
    try {
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], 
            new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager(){
                @Override public void checkClientTrusted(
                     X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) 
                throws CertificateException {}

                @Override public void checkServerTrusted(
                     X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) 
                throws CertificateException {}

                @Override public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }}}, new SecureRandom());
        SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

        URL url = null;

        url = new URL("https://tlauncher.org/repo/test" +
                      "/ConfigPreMasterSALF-2.18.json");

        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnectio) url.openConnection();
        conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
           @Override public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
              return true;
           }
        });
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            conn.getInputStream(),"utf8"));

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The server has the signing sertification.
How can i improve or implement another way the work with server?

Answer (score 0):

Returning null from getAcceptedIssuers tells the validation method in your client code to mistrust any certificate the HTTPS server is holding. Such the client will never trust the server and the connection can not be made. To make it work you should return the Certifacte Authority's (CA) certificate, the one the authority used to sign the servers certificate. Let's call that CA certificate the root of trust. Anyhow, that's a lot of footwork you are doing here while Java has prebuilt facilities for which you can find lots of examples online.

The library you are using is known as the JCA Java Cryptography Architecture and it has means to store such certificates for future use. Use the JCA's keytool to import the root of trust into a key-store and activate that key-store before opening a secured connection to the server.

Illustration how the JCA supports SSL/TLS which in turn is used for the 'S' in HTTPS can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#SSLTLS it also introduces the KeyManager, TrustManager and KeyStore facilities in more detail.

Anyway, I've tried the URL your pointing your code at and it works perfectly fine in Firefox Browser and in Java too. It bears a valid SSL Certificate from COMODO CA. If this is the real URL your trying to fetch you can forget about the JCA completely, skip setting the SSLContext and open the connection without the Verifier.

```
URL url = new URL("https://tlauncher.org/repo/test/ConfigPreMasterSALF-2.18.json");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        conn.getInputStream(),"utf8"));
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
}
reader.close();
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some problems with your current version:

1. Your SSLContext is misconfigured.  You are better off not setting an SSLContext<sup>1</sup>.  That will cause the SSL stack to use the default one, which will use the trusted roots in the JRE's keystore.
2. Your HostnameVerifier is going to accept any hostname, which makes it pointless to add one.  (That is what the default verifier does.)
3. If you are going to use a HostnameVerifier, it must be set before the connection is established.  The way to do this is to use the static `setDefaultHostnameVerifier` method.
4. Code potentially leaks Socket file descriptors.  The reader should be closed in a `finally` block.

---

<sup>1 - You might use an SSLContext if you needed to override what is in the keystore or do something else that is different to normal behavior.  For example, you might want to turn off verification on some known trusted server that has an expired cert.  Or you might want to *distrust* a given root CA.</sup>